# Scope bar visible behind UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I encounter this strange behavior in iOS9, where the scope bar is visible right behind the UISearchBar when the ViewController appears for the first time:

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRNHC.png)

After pressing "Search" the UISearchBar behaves as expected (UISearchBar moves to the top with the scope bar below). After completion of the search or hitting cancel it returns to the state I would like to have from the beginning:

[Subsequent correct look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUBO.png)

In the viewDidLoad method I initialize the UISearchController as follows:

```
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[[self titleForScopeButton:ScopeButtonIdNameDesc],
                                                          [self titleForScopeButton:ScopeButtonIP]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked in a bit on that app and forgot that I set the overall appearance of the UISearchBar in the appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[PCConstantsGUI tintColor]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[PCConstantsGUI tintColor]];
```

The culprit causing the rendering problem was the "UISearchBarStyleMinimal" that looked nifty before I had to replace the deprecated UISearchDisplayController with UISearchController.